# TensorFlow: How to set learning rate decay based on epochs?

Tags: tensorflow

The learning rate decay function `tf.train.exponential_decay` takes a `decay_steps` parameter. To decrease the learning rate every `num_epochs`, you would set `decay_steps = num_epochs * num_train_examples / batch_size`. However, when reading data from `.tfrecords` files, you don't know how many training examples there are inside them.

To get `num_train_examples`, you could:

- Set up a `tf.string_input_producer` with `num_epochs=1`.
- Run this through `tf.TFRecordReader`/`tf.parse_single_example`.
- Loop and count how many times it produces some output before stopping.

However, this isn't very elegant.

Is there an easier way to either get the number of training examples from a `.tfrecords` file or set the learning rate decay based on epochs instead of steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the number of records in a `.tfrecords` file :

```
def get_num_records(tf_record_file):
  return len([x for x in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(tf_record_file)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the learning_rate below,

```
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                           100000, 0.96, staircase=True)
```

starter_learning_rate can be changed after desired epochs by defining a function like:

```
def initial_learning_rate(epoch):
    if (epoch >= 0) and (epoch < 100):
        return 0.1
    if (epoch >= 100) and (epoch < 200):
        return 0.05
    if (epoch >= 200) and (epoch < 500):
        return 0.001
```

And then you may initialize your starter_learning_rate inside the for loop (iterating over epochs) as:

```
for epoch in range(epochs): #epochs is the total number of epochs
starter_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate(epoch)
...
```

**Note**

The global_step variable is not changed in:

```
decayed_learning_rate = starter_learning_rate *
                        decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you set the learning rate decay according to the changes of the training or evaluation loss. If the loss is oscillating you can decrease the learning rate. Hardly can you predict from which epoch or step you should decrease it before the training starts.