# How to get epoch num info from tf.train.string_input_producer

Tags: tensorflow

If reading files using string_input_producer, like

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
  files, 
  num_epochs=num_epochs,
  shuffle=shuffle)
```

how can I get epoch num info during training(I want to show this info during training)
I tried below

```
run 
tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('input_train/input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs:0')
```

will always the same as the limit epoch num.

```
run
tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('input_train/input_producer/limit_epochs/CountUpTo:0')
```

will each time add 1..

Both can not get correct epoch num during training.

Another thing is ,if retrain from existing model, can I got the epoch num info already trained?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899939/tensorflow-how-to-set-learning-rate-decay-based-on-epochs

Answer (score 1):

I think the right approach here is to define a `global_step` variable that you pass to your optimizer (or you can increment it manually).

The [TensorFlow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html) tutorial provides an example:

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Now `global_step` will be incremented each time the `train_op` runs. Since you know the size of your dataset and your batch size, you will know what epoch you're currently at.

When you save your model with a `tf.train.Saver()`, the `global_step` variable will also be saved. When you restore your model, you can just call `global_step.eval()` to get back the step value where you left off.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks chillinger I find cifa10 use same strategy. But I think we can get epoch num  anyway.. and it is useful for training large data.